# Does Azure Search Provides Etags for managing concurrency for Add, Update or Delete Documents?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, optimistic-concurrency

[How to manage concurrency in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-concurrency)

here it is said that Azure Search offers an optimistic concurrency model. There are no locks on a resource. Instead, there is an ETag for every resource that identifies the resource version so that you can craft requests that avoid accidental overwrites.

But [Add, Update or Delete Documents (Azure Search Service REST API)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) has not mentioned anything about etags. Does Azure Search Provides Etags for managing concurrency for Add, Update or Delete Documents?

Comment: Reading the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/common-http-request-and-response-headers-used-in-azure-search, I don't think optimistic concurrency is supported for document related operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately we do not yet support using document version for managing concurrent add/delete/update operations on documents. As of now, as you mentioned, we only provide etags when managing "non-documents" resources (such as index definitions, synonym maps, data sources, etc.)

Please upvote the following user voice suggestion to help us prioritize the work to add support for document versioning

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/10413003-document-version-support-for-data-consistency-and