# How do we handle concurrent writes to Azure Search documents?

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-cognitive-search

## Use Case and Question

1. making one network call to fetch a document from search into memory,
2. then changing that document in memory, and
3. finally making a second network call to update that document in search.

***How can we guarantee that step (3) fails if the document has changed since step (1).***

Using an ETag in the request header seems ideal. We found docs on doing that for non-document resources (e.g., index fields), but we found scant documentation on doing that with document resources.

## Our Research

- The .NET v11 `SearchClient` provides .NET methods for the update and the merge operations, but does not explicitly mention concurrency in the XML comments of those methods.
- In the source code for the v11 `SearchClient`, both the upload and merge operations call into [`IndexDocumentsInternal`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/b58a2ef7266eb0c1981fa48e91e74786baf03323/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/src/SearchClient.cs#L1301). That method has no explicit ETag usage (and it ends up calling into the REST API).
- The [REST API headers documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/common-http-request-and-response-headers-used-in-azure-search) says of ETags that it supports *indexers, indexes, and data sources, but not documents*.
- The [REST API response documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents#response) includes a 409; however, the docs do not give a lot of information on when this response would be returned. The 409 means that a, *version conflict was detected when attempting to index a document. This can happen when you're trying to index the same document more than once concurrently.*

This related SO item does not answer our question: [Does Azure Search Provides Etags for managing concurrency for Add, Update or Delete Documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228434/does-azure-search-provides-etags-for-managing-concurrency-for-add-update-or-del)